# .img-responsive bootstrap issue responsive design. Image is stuck at 25% width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I want to make responsive design for my webpage and it seems that its not working. Media query which is 1600px works fine, but when I am trying to do mobile version (480px) my gallery pictures is only 25% width, and it is not changing.

HTML :

```
<section id="works" class="works-section">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class='spotlightWrapper'>  
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12"><h1>Works</h1></div>
                        </div>

                        <ul>
                          <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <li><a href="img/cover.jpg" data-lightbox="portfolio" data-title="My caption"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/1.png"/></a></li>
                            <li><a href="img/cover.jpg" data-lightbox="portfolio" data-title="My caption"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/2.jpg"/></a></li>
                          </div>


                          <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <div class="col-lg-3"<li><a href="img/cover.jpg" data-lightbox="portfolio" data-title="My caption"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/3.jpg"/></a></li></div>
                            <li><a href="img/cover.jpg" data-lightbox="portfolio" data-title="My caption"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/4.jpg"/></a></li>
                          </div>


                          <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <li><a href="img/cover.jpg" data-lightbox="portfolio" data-title="My caption"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/5.jpg"/></a></li>
                            <li><a href="img/cover.jpg" data-lightbox="portfolio" data-title="My caption"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/6.jpg"/></a></li>
                          </div>


                          <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <li><a href="img/cover.jpg" data-lightbox="portfolio" data-title="My caption"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/7.jpg"/></a></li>
                            <li><a href="img/cover.jpg" data-lightbox="portfolio" data-title="My caption"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/8.jpg"/></a></li>
                          </div>

                            <div class='clear'></div>  
                        </ul>  
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Css media query:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {

    #about .col-lg-3 {
        max-height: 420px;
    }

    .spotlightWrapper  .col-lg-3 li {
        width: 100%;
    }

    ul .col-lg-3 .img-responsive {
        width: 100%;
        height: 200px;
    }

    #contact .col-lg-2 {
        height: 200px;
    }

    #contact .col-lg-2 .fa {
        padding: 0 auto;
    }

    #FirstPicture {
        display: none;
    }

    .spotlightWrapper ul {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you set your viewport meta tag appropriately?

Comment: i have it like this.

<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

Comment: That looks correct for the viewport. Just wanted to make sure it wasn't something that simple (it happens to the best of us!) :)

Comment: Maybe you see what is wrong with the code? :)

Comment: don't overwrite bootstrap classes, just use div.col-lg-3.col-xs-12 for example, this way you'll be sure that it'll work properly since you'll set a specific grid rules for mobile layout

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are facing this issue is that you have used img-responsive class which always works with the ratio of parent div. Here you have specified **col-lg-3** so in a 12 unit grid 3 would be 25% of it.

**Solution:**

If you are using media query than please remove img-responsive class from the image so that it does not inherit the width from parent div.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are attempting to override current twitter bootstrap classes for your media query. I would guess that you are having a conflict between the the css you have written and the twitter bootstrap css. Try using the predefined bootstrap classes for small screen sizes by just adding an additional class for that size like so

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12"> ... </div>
```

You're .img-responsive will then conform to the size of the div that it is in